# setVisibility(View.GONE) doesn't disappear a view

Tags: android

In my activity, I have a start button, and when that's clicked it should fade out and finally disappear by `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

The problem is setting visibility to GONE doesn't disappear the view, it's still visible. I've purposefully made the view animation fade out to 0.1 (instead of 0) and I can see it in the background even after I've called `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it.

The fadeout animation `anim_fade_out.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true" android:fillEnabled="true">

        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.1"
            android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

The method is `showTimer()`:

```
private void showTimer() {
    final LinearLayout startButtonArea = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.startButtonArea);      

    Animation animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_fade_out);

    startButtonArea.startAnimation(animFadeOut);

    animFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startButtonArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("Animation ended","startButtonArea SHOULD BE GONE BUT IT ISN'T");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}    
    });

}
```

To reiterate, I know that the end alpha of the animation is 0.1 (it would be 0 usually) but I want to confirm that the view is really `GONE` and it isn't.

Comment: Try using INVISIBLE instead of gone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `fillAfter` is true, the animation sets the properties after your `onAnimationEnd` is called. You can either change `fillAfter` to false, or do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startButtonArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("Animation ended","startButtonArea SHOULD BE GONE BUT IT ISN'T");
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Serves me right for just copying the animation XML without understanding every bit of it.

Comment: Nah, we are developers. Thats what we do :)