# View.GONE doesn't work after Translate Animation

Tags: android, animation

So I have an app that when the user hits a `button` will do an `animation` for a `layout` with buttons (like a `sliding menu`) and then if he hits another button it has to make invisible or gone the first layout and then so the new one.

But when I am trying to make on the `AnimationStart` my `layout` with buttons invisible, it doesn't do that.

I already tried some solutions from here:

[Why doesn't setvisibility work after a view is animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690029/why-doesnt-setvisibility-work-after-a-view-is-animated)

[Setvisibilityview Gone doesn't disappear a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062271/setvisibilityview-gone-doesnt-disappear-a-view)

but nothing worked!

Any help??

**`Java code` (it's the same for both buttons)**

```
 btn_home1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   btn_home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   btn_book.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   btn_find_us.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   btn_menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 0, 0,0 );   
                slide.setDuration(1000);   
                slide.setFillAfter(true);   
                slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                   btn_home2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   btn_book2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   btn_find_us2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   btn_menu2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 0);
                          btn_home.setClickable(false);  
                          btn_book.setClickable(false);  
                          btn_find_us.setClickable(false);  
                          btn_menu.setClickable(false);                           
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                          btn_home.setClickable(true);  
                          btn_book.setClickable(true);  
                          btn_find_us.setClickable(true);  
                          btn_menu.setClickable(true);      
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                btn_menu.startAnimation(slide);
                btn_book.startAnimation(slide);
                btn_find_us.startAnimation(slide);  
                btn_home.startAnimation(slide); 
                layout1.startAnimation(slide);
                }
        });
```

**`XML` code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#BE2625" >
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:text="342"
                 />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:text="34243"
                 />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lala"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lala1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_us2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the view to invisible after the animation?

Comment: Update! I do it on AnimationStart, so both layout and buttons can be invisible or gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done again a research on this link: [Why doesn't setVisibility work after a view is animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690029/why-doesnt-setvisibility-work-after-a-view-is-animated?rq=1)

And found the answer of @Chris Knight:

`Another way to work around this is to wrap your animated view in another view and set the visibility of that wrapper view.`

So I used as he did two `FrameLayout` and then set the `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for one at a time, because the user would hit one button at a time so it would open a `Slide Menu` at a time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#BE2625" >
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:text="342"
                 />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:text="34243"
                 />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/lsd1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dp">  

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lala"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>     

       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/lsd2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dp">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lala1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_book2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_us2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_menu2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  />


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>     

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

calling **clearAnimation** of the View fixed the problem. In my case I wanted to set the View back to its original position after doing a translation with fillAfter set to true.